# Is it safe to iterate over synchronized wrappers?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I decided to dig into source code a bit and noticed that [`Collections.synchronizedList(List)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) is implemented as follows:

```
public static <T> List<T> synchronizedList(List<T> list) {
    return (list instanceof RandomAccess ?
        new SynchronizedRandomAccessList<T>(list) :
        new SynchronizedList<T>(list));
}
```

where the [`SynchronizedList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.SynchronizedList) nested class is:

```
static class SynchronizedList<E>
extends SynchronizedCollection<E>
            implements List<E> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7754090372962971524L;
    final List<E> list;

    SynchronizedList(List<E> list) {
        super(list);
        this.list = list;
    }
    SynchronizedList(List<E> list, Object mutex) {
        super(list, mutex);
        this.list = list;
    }

    public boolean More ...equals(Object o) {
        synchronized(mutex) {return list.equals(o);}
    }

    //ommited

    public void add(int index, E element) {
        synchronized(mutex) {list.add(index, element);}
    }

    public E remove(int index) {
        synchronized(mutex) {return list.remove(index);}
    }

    //rest is ommited
}
```

As can bee seen, the class useses a `private` lock object to provide thread-safety. But [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) allows us to iterate over it using locking on the objetct returned by the factory method.

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned
>   list when iterating over it:

So, we use different locks for iterating and modifying list (`add`, `remove`, etc).

Why is it considered to be safe?

Comment: _So, we use different locks for iterating and modifying list_ What makes you think so?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The source code I quoted. In the nested class we use synchronized(mutex) which is not accesible from outside.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Collections#synchronizedList` method

```
public static <T> List<T> synchronizedList(List<T> list) {
    return (list instanceof RandomAccess ?
            new SynchronizedRandomAccessList<>(list) :
            new SynchronizedList<>(list));
}
```

uses that single parameter constructor that you've shown in your question. That constructor invokes the super constructor which sets `this` as the `mutex`. All the methods are `synchronized` on `mutex`, `this`.

The documentation is telling you to also synchronize on the instance while iterating. That reference is the same as the `this` within the method bodies.

All these actions are (should, if you do it right) therefore sharing the same lock.